# OS X Mountain Lion: how set system-level environment variable with referenced value?

Tags: environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion

According to posts here such as [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x), for Mountain Lion, if not for earlier version of OS X, the only way to set environment variables at the *system* level is to use (or create) a file /etc/launchd.conf that contains commands such as:

```
setenv CATALINA_BASE /opt/local/share/java/tomcat6
```

(That does seem to work as expected.)

If so, how does one do this by referencing the value of something else, e.g., to set JAVA_HOME? In /etc/launchd.conf I tried

```
setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

but then in Terminal if I run

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I just get back literally $(/usr/libexec/java_home).

By contrast, if I put that same setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home) command into my ~/.profile, then the result of echo $JAVA_HOME is the actual value referenced, namely, /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home.

So how should I modify the setenv command in /etc/launchd.conf so as to cause it to give the *value* of the second argument rather than the literal second argument?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to append to the existing path, you can, from the terminal, do something like "echo setenv PATH $PATH:/path_addition >> /etc/launchd.conf" The launchd.conf can't, itself, contain the variable, but if you know the values you want to use before hand, you can use that to inject them. Alternately, create a separate script that does something similar for you.

Comment: I wasn't trying to append to the path, but rather to do explicitly what I asked: to set a value globally for environment variable JAVA_HOME. (So many times I see posts about setting environment variables in general, but they're really just about PATH -- which of course is just one environment variable.)

Comment: It should be the same principle. You just need to resolve the variable prior to adding it to launchd.conf